# I have a big empty space between my div container and my html table inside this div

Tags: html, css, datatables, html-table

I am using jquery plugin datatables and the css demo_table.css that has been using in the example in the home page of DataTables.net. The problem is on top the table, there is a huge space on the top of the table, I use margin and padding but the space is the same and when I put the margin or padding with values bigger than zero the space seems to be a real element because the space is bigger than before. I will put the CSS code and the html code generated:

HTML:

```
<div id="table_chart_placeholder">

<div class="dataTables_wrapper" id="table_chart_wrapper"><div id="table_chart_length" class="dataTables_length"><label>Show <select name="table_chart_length" size="1"><option value="10">10</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option></select> entries</label></div><div class="dataTables_filter" id="table_chart_filter"><label>Search: <input type="text"></label></div><div class="dataTables_scroll"><div class="dataTables_scrollHead" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; border: 0pt none; width: 100%;"><div class="dataTables_scrollHeadInner" style="width: 713px;"><table class="display" style="margin-left: 0pt; width: 697px;"><thead>
    <tr><th class="sorting_asc" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 68px;">Provincias</th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 45px;">1993
            </th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 45px;">1994
            </tr>
    </thead></table></div></div><div class="dataTables_scrollBody" style="overflow: auto; width: 100%;"><table class="display" id="table_chart" style="margin-left: 0pt; width: 110%;"><thead>
    <tr style="height: 0px;"><th class="sorting_asc" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 68px; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt; border-top-width: 0pt; border-bottom-width: 0pt; height: 0pt;"></th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 45px; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt; border-top-width: 0pt; border-bottom-width: 0pt; height: 0pt;"></th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 45px; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt; border-top-width: 0pt; border-bottom-width: 0pt; height: 0pt;"></th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 45px; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt; border-top-width: 0pt; border-bottom-width: 0pt; height: 0pt;"></th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 45px; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt; border-top-width: 0pt; border-bottom-width: 0pt; height: 0pt;"></th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 52px; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt; border-top-width: 0pt; border-bottom-width: 0pt; height: 0pt;"></th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 52px; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt; border-top-width: 0pt; border-bottom-width: 0pt; height: 0pt;"></th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 52px; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt; border-top-width: 0pt; border-bottom-width: 0pt; height: 0pt;"></th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 45px; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt; border-top-width: 0pt; border-bottom-width: 0pt; height: 0pt;"></th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 52px; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt; border-top-width: 0pt; border-bottom-width: 0pt; height: 0pt;"></th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 45px; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt; border-top-width: 0pt; border-bottom-width: 0pt; height: 0pt;"></th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 52px; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt; border-top-width: 0pt; border-bottom-width: 0pt; height: 0pt;"></th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 45px; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt; border-top-width: 0pt; border-bottom-width: 0pt; height: 0pt;"></th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 45px; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt; border-top-width: 0pt; border-bottom-width: 0pt; height: 0pt;"></th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 52px; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt; border-top-width: 0pt; border-bottom-width: 0pt; height: 0pt;"></th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 52px; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt; border-top-width: 0pt; border-bottom-width: 0pt; height: 0pt;"></th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 52px; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt; border-top-width: 0pt; border-bottom-width: 0pt; height: 0pt;"></th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 52px; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt; border-top-width: 0pt; border-bottom-width: 0pt; height: 0pt;"></th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 52px; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt; border-top-width: 0pt; border-bottom-width: 0pt; height: 0pt;"></th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 52px; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt; border-top-width: 0pt; border-bottom-width: 0pt; height: 0pt;"></th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 52px; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt; border-top-width: 0pt; border-bottom-width: 0pt; height: 0pt;"></th></tr>
    </thead>


<tbody><tr class="odd">
            <td class=" sorting_1">Artemisa</td>
            <td>1,06148</td>
             </tr><tr class="even">
            <td class=" sorting_1">Camaguey</td>
             <td>3,62712</td>
             </tr><tr class="odd">
            <td class=" sorting_1">Ciego de Avila</td>
             <td>1,19476</td>
             </tr><tr class="even">
            <td class=" sorting_1">Cienfuegos</td>
             <td>1,63268</td>
             </tr><tr class="odd">
            <td class=" sorting_1">Granma</td>
             <td>1,11384</td>
              </tr><tr class="even">
            <td class=" sorting_1">Guantanamo</td>
             <td>1,11384</td> 
             </tr><tr class="odd">
            <td class=" sorting_1">Holguin</td>
             <td>2,20292</td>
             </tr><tr class="even">
            <td class=" sorting_1">Isla de la Juventud</td>
             <td>0,53312</td>
              </tr><tr class="odd">
            <td class=" sorting_1">La Habana</td>

             <td>20,72504</td> 
             </tr><tr class="even">
            <td class=" sorting_1">Las Tunas</td>
             <td>1,22189</td> 
                </tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="dataTables_info" id="table_chart_info">Showing 1 to 10 of 16 entries</div><div class="dataTables_paginate paging_two_button" id="table_chart_paginate"><div class="paginate_disabled_previous" title="Previous" id="table_chart_previous"></div><div class="paginate_enabled_next" title="Next" id="table_chart_next"></div></div></div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.dataTables_wrapper {
position: relative;
min-height: 302px;
clear: both;
_height: 302px;
zoom: 1;}

.dataTables_processing {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 250px;
height: 30px;
margin-left: -125px;
margin-top: -15px;
padding: 14px 0 2px 0;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
text-align: center;
color: #999;
font-size: 14px;
background-color: white;}

.dataTables_length {
width: 40%;
float: left;}

.dataTables_filter {
width: 50%;
float: right;
text-align: right;}

.dataTables_info {
width: 60%;
float: left;}

.dataTables_paginate {
width: 44px;
* width: 50px;
float: right;
text-align: right;}

table.display {
margin: 0 auto;
clear: both;
width: 100%;    }

table.display thead th {
padding: 3px 18px 3px 10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;
* cursor: hand;}

table.display tfoot th {
padding: 3px 18px 3px 10px;
border-top: 1px solid black;
font-weight: bold;}

table.display tr.heading2 td {
border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;}

table.display td {
padding: 3px 10px;}

table.display td.center {
text-align: center;}

table.display tr.odd.gradeA {
background-color: #ddffdd;}

table.display tr.even.gradeA {
background-color: #eeffee;}

table.display tr.odd.gradeC {
background-color: #ddddff;}

table.display tr.even.gradeC {
background-color: #eeeeff;}

table.display tr.odd.gradeX {
background-color: #ffdddd;}

table.display tr.even.gradeX {
background-color: #ffeeee;}

table.display tr.odd.gradeU {
background-color: #ddd;}

table.display tr.even.gradeU {
background-color: #eee;}

tr.odd {
background-color: #E2E4FF;}

tr.even {
background-color: white;}

.dataTables_scroll {
  clear: both;}

.dataTables_scrollBody {
    *margin-top: -1px;}
.top, .bottom {
    padding: 15px;
background-color: #F5F5F5;
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;}

.top .dataTables_info {
float: none;}

.clear {
clear: both;}

.dataTables_empty {
text-align: center;}
```

Comment: you should try to post minimal code which is doing problems. No one will read try to debug your looong code. And possibly post URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just gone through your code ,there is no space on top of table.
You can use width=100% instead of 110%.

```
.display{
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 110%;
}
```

Try it. For margin or padding use float:left; in your CSS.

Comment: that is right, there is no html element that represent the empty space, but the empty space is still there and I don´t know what else can I do

Comment: If the empty space is there, but no extra elements, it's certainly going to be all about CSS. Remember that the "header" and "footer", while they may be visually integrated with the table (usually) are actually divs. You might be applying some sort of padding or margin to the divs rather than the table. Without a live link, it will be impossible to tell what the culprit is. Also, if you're activating bJQueryUI, there is other CSS unaccounted for.

Comment: the problem was the float and clear properties in the css, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Datatbles creates a wrapper with a min-height of 302px thato sometimes causes problem, have you tried removing it?

```
.dataTables_wrapper {
position: relative;
min-height: 302px;//remove this
clear: both;
_height: 302px;//remove this
zoom: 1;}
```

Comment: that doesn´t work @Nicola, the wrapper of the tables is inside a div named table_chart_placeholder and the html generated looks like that, but I give a height of 400 px to the div table_chart_placeholder and the webpage show the table wrapper outside of the div container when in the html is inside. That is driving me crazy. Sorry I don´t have a link, the web site is not public yet.